# How to insert data with explicit id property which has null value?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have a js object with explicit `id` property. Like this:

```
const data = {
  user_id: null,
  user_email: faker.internet.email()
};
```

The value of `user_id` is null and there is a `users` table using `user_id` as its primary key.

I want to insert this data correctly and I hope `knex` can obey the primary key increment rule.

Here is my code:

```
async function insert(user: any) {
  return await knex('users')
    .insert(user)
    .returning('*');
}
```

When I try to insert this data, got an error:

> error: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of `user_id` to `undefined`. Then it will insert the data and 
obey the primary key increment rule.

```
const data = {
  user_id: undefined,
  user_email: faker.internet.email()
};
```

Check the inserted row in `users` table. The value of `user_id` is `1`